# Proxy setting via the QGIS global_settings.ini

Tags: qgis

I would like to specify the proxy for our company in qgis global_settings.ini. So that the proxy is entered under Option / General. Is the?

example

[image]

Furthermore, I would like to have removed the check mark "Show QGIS news on welcome page" via global_settings.ini.

If I enter the following:
NewsFeed\httpsfeedqgisorg\disabled=true
the check mark is still set

Does anyone have an idea?

P.S. I don't want to make the setting in QGIS3.ini, but globally.

(It's about that hook)

[image]